# Margins for different pages

Tags: margins

I'm new to LaTeX and don't know which command to use to create an exclusive margin for a single page and then return to the general margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage [top= 1cm, left= 4cm, bottom= 2cm, rigth= 2cm]{geometry}
\title{Test}
\author{Eduardo }
\date{Junio 2023}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is very unspecific. Can you please make it more concrete and add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that illustrates, where, why and how you want to change which margins? Currently I can only tell you, that [package `geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) provides commands `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry`.

Comment: Sorry. For example i want , in the title page, other margin

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage [top= 1cm, left= 4cm, bottom= 2cm, rigth= 2cm]{geometry}
\title{Test}
\author{Eduardo }
\date{Junio 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}

Comment: Your example does not compile, nor does it show, which margin change your want. Please edit the question.

Comment: @Eduardo It might be easier to create your title page separately and then include it via the `pdfpages` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\maketitle` with class `article`, you should use option `titlepage` to have a title page instead of a in-page title. And if the title page should be, e.g., a cover with other margins, you can use, e.g., class `scrartcl` with option `titlepage=firstiscover` or package `scrextend` and options `extendedfeatures=title` and `titlepage=firstiscover` and define `\coverpagetopmargin`, `\coverpagebottommargin`, `\coverpageleftmargin`, `\coverpagerightmargin`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage [top= 1cm, left= 4cm, bottom= 2cm, right= 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[extendedfeature=title,titlepage=firstiscover]{scrextend}
\renewcommand*{\coverpageleftmargin}{5cm}
\renewcommand*{\coverpageleftmargin}{5cm}
\renewcommand*{\coverpagetopmargin}{5cm}
\setkomafont{title}{\bfseries}
\title{Se trata de un título de prueba en varias líneas para aclarar los márgenes}
\author{Eduardo}
\date{Junio 2023}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introducción}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or similar with `scrartcl`:

```
\documentclass[titlepage=firstiscover]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage [top= 1cm, left= 4cm, bottom= 2cm, right= 2cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\coverpageleftmargin}{5cm}
\renewcommand*{\coverpageleftmargin}{5cm}
\renewcommand*{\coverpagetopmargin}{5cm}
\setkomafont{title}{\bfseries}
\title{Se trata de un título de prueba en varias líneas para aclarar los márgenes}
\author{Eduardo}
\date{Junio 2023}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introducción}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the difference in page size, because default with `article` is `letterpaper` but default with `scrartcl` is `a4paper`.

However something like this can also be reached without `scrextend` using `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry`:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage [top= 1cm, left= 4cm, bottom= 2cm, right= 2cm]{geometry}
\title{Se trata de un título de prueba en varias líneas para aclarar los márgenes}
\author{Eduardo}
\date{Junio 2023}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=5cm,left=5cm,right=5cm}
\maketitle
\restoregeometry
\section{Introducción}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or from within the document preamble, using [generic LaTeX hook](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf):

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage [top= 1cm, left= 4cm, bottom= 2cm, right= 2cm]{geometry}
\title{Se trata de un título de prueba en varias líneas para aclarar los márgenes}
\author{Eduardo}
\date{Junio 2023}
\AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/before}{\newgeometry{top=5cm,left=5cm,right=5cm}}
\AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/after}{\restoregeometry}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introducción}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as shown in the previous example.

Comment: I was a bit complicated with this topic, but with this it is very clear to me how to do it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Eduardo If the answer was helpful, please see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)